# Why are my AWS Sagemaker Data Science 3.0 ipywidgets no longer displaying? ('error displaying widget: model not found')

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker, ipywidgets

AWS Sagemaker Data Science 3.0 (Python 3.10) image no longer displaying ipywidget widgets. Worked yesterday but this morning only getting `error displaying widget: model not found` for any widget load when I started a new kernel. Any idea what would make this happen? Tried downgrading to Data Science (Python 3.7) image but the `interactive_output` function seems to fail there, plus it worked for weeks on the Data Science 3.0 image. Any thoughts of things to try?

Simplest version of Code that should work

```
import ipywidgets as wgs
from IPython.display import display
w = wgs.IntSlider()
display(w)
```

Tried loading a previously successful plot with interactive_output() call.  The plot displays, but the widgets do not - just a banner of `Error displaying widget: model not found` lines underneath.

Comment: Is there something specific you're trying? The code snippet you shared here works for me in both DS and DS 3.0 images.